dutch national flag algorithm with only "if" not using "else if or else"
works:
vector<int> nums = {2,0,2,1,1,0};
int low = 0,mid = 0,high = nums.size() - 1;

        while(mid<=high){
            if(nums[mid]==0){
                swap(nums[mid],nums[low]);
                mid++;
                low++;
            }
            else if(nums[mid]==1){
                mid++;
            }
            else if(nums[mid]==2){
                swap(nums[mid],nums[high]);
                high--;
            }
        }

if i use only "if" 3 times the code doesn't work,but on 1 time use it works ,why?
doesn't work:
vector<int> nums = {2,0,2,1,1,0};
int low = 0,mid = 0,high = nums.size() - 1;

        while(mid<=high){
            if(nums[mid]==0){
                swap(nums[mid],nums[low]);
                mid++;
                low++;
            }
            if(nums[mid]==1){
                mid++;
            }
            if(nums[mid]==2){
                swap(nums[mid],nums[high]);
                high--;
            }
        }

i tried to solve this sort colors problem on leetcode ,if i use only if statement it doesn't works.

Think about x = 0; if (x == 0) {x = 1;} else {x = 2;} and x = 0; if (x == 0) {x = 1;} x = 2;. What is the value of x after each one?

When you stepped through the code in a debugger what differences in behavior did you observe?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems ; observe mid and nums[mid]

Questions about competitive coding algorithms belong on competitive coding forums.

What is the code supposed to do? What does it do instead?

dutch national flag algorithm. Dutch flag problem. I.e. sorting out a range filled by three different values.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You don't have to do mid++ immediately. You can do new_mid = mid + 1; and update mid at the end.

@PepjinKramer it's canonical problem formulated by Dijkstra https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem I'm surprised that people today don't recognize it. It also known as three-way partitioning.  Looks more like OP tried to "play"with code and didn't identify the problem

You're altering mid within first branch. In first version your three-way partitioning excludes other branches, which is equal to:
    while(mid<=high){
        if(nums[mid]==0){
            swap(nums[mid],nums[low]);
            mid++;
            low++;
            continue;
        }
        if(nums[mid]==1){
            mid++;
            continue;
        }
        if(nums[mid]==2){
            swap(nums[mid],nums[high]);
            high--;
            continue;
        }
    }

But in second variant other branches test new value of num[mid].
In C++ in can be written in less wordy way (and it is sliightly faster because nums[mid] for comparison is evaluated once):
while(mid<=high)
switch(nums[mid]) {
case 0: swap(nums[mid++],nums[low++]); continue;
case 2: swap(nums[mid],nums[high--]); continue;
case 1: mid++; 
}

PS. You may try to benchmark an iterator version
